# Register for Parse Remote Notifications in ViewController Outside of App Delegate

Tags: ios, swift

I have a ViewController with an @IBAction for a button that prompts a user to register for notifications by calling a method in the AppDelegate

```
class PermissionModalViewController: UIViewController {

let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate

@IBAction func presentPermissions(sender: AnyObject) {
    appDelegate.askNotificationsPermissions()
}
```

In my AppDelegate.swift, I have the "didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken" function

```
func askNotificationsPermissions() {
        if(UIApplication.instancesRespondToSelector(Selector("registerUserNotificationSettings:"))){
            println("i'm asking the do you want notifications question!")
            UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerUserNotificationSettings(UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: .Alert | .Sound, categories: nil))
        }
    }

       func application(application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: NSData) {
            println("successful register for push")
            let installation = PFInstallation.currentInstallation()
            installation.setDeviceTokenFromData(deviceToken)
            installation.saveInBackground()
        }
```

According to this answer, [Register for remote notifications outside of app delegate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17182857/register-for-remote-notifications-outside-of-app-delegate) I should call the method in my AppDelegate that does the notifications registration (appDelegate.askNotificationPermissions() in my case)

However, my callback, "didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken" does not get triggered.  Why doesn't "didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken" not get triggered?

Answer (score 1):

OK, was able to figure this out.

In my AppDelegate.swift file I have the methods:

```
func askNotificationsPermissions() {
    if(UIApplication.instancesRespondToSelector(Selector("registerUserNotificationSettings:"))){
        println("i'm asking the question!")
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerUserNotificationSettings(UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: .Badge | .Alert | .Sound, categories: nil))
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerForRemoteNotifications()
    }
}

func application(application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: NSData) {
    println("successful register for push")
    let installation = PFInstallation.currentInstallation()
    installation.setDeviceTokenFromData(deviceToken)
    installation.saveInBackground()
}

func application(application: UIApplication, didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError error: NSError) {
    if error.code == 3010 {
        println("Push notifications are not supported in the iOS Simulator.")
    } else {
        println("application:didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError: %@", error)
    }
}
```

In my ViewController.swift that I'm using to trigger the request to the user to give us permission to send remote notifications:

class PermissionModalViewController: UIViewController {

```
let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate

@IBAction func presentPermissions(sender: AnyObject) {
    appDelegate.askNotificationsPermissions()
}
```

In a nutshell, I called the askNotificationsPermissions() function that was defined in the AppDelegate from my ViewController.

Another piece that I had left out in my original question was registerForRemoteNotifications() which is a method that I call in the askNotificationsPermissions() questions.  This needed to be there to trigger the `didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken` callback

Comment: This function was called successfully but caused a crash.