# Register for voip notifications outside of app delegate

Tags: ios, swift

My app requires onboarding and I want to wait until the user reach the AskForVOIPNotificationsViewController before I ask for permission to present push/voip notifications. The code below kind of works, the problem is that pushRegistry in AppDelegate does not realise it has permission and  didUpdatePushCredentials in AppDelegate does not get called. The code is never run and the server never gets the device token.  However if I close the app and relaunch, didUpdatePushCredentials is called, the server gets the token and the user is able to receive notifications.

How can I make sure didUpdatePushCredentials/PKPushRegistry is called from AskForVOIPNotificationsViewController so that the user is able to receive voip notifications immediately without relaunching the app?

I implemented my code according to a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17182857/register-for-remote-notifications-outside-of-app-delegate), but I am unable to get it to work with PushKit.

Any help is VERY much appreciated - thank you !

> In AskForVOIPNotificationsViewController

```
func registerForNotifications() {
    let notificationSettings: UIUserNotificationSettings! = UIApplication.sharedApplication().currentUserNotificationSettings()
    if !notificationSettings.types.contains([.Badge, .Sound, .Alert])  {
        let notificationTypes: UIUserNotificationType = [.Badge, .Sound, .Alert]
        let notificationSettings = UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: notificationTypes, categories: nil)
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerUserNotificationSettings(notificationSettings)
    }
}
```

> In App delegate

```
import UIKit
import PushKit

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, PKPushRegistryDelegate {

    var voipRegistry:PKPushRegistry!
    var window: UIWindow?



    func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

        registerForVoIPPushes()
        return true
    }


    func registerForVoIPPushes() {
        voipRegistry = PKPushRegistry(queue: dispatch_get_main_queue())
        voipRegistry.delegate = self
        voipRegistry.desiredPushTypes = Set([PKPushTypeVoIP])
        print("VOIP Push registered")
    }


    func pushRegistry(registry: PKPushRegistry!, didUpdatePushCredentials credentials: PKPushCredentials!, forType type: String!) {

        let voipToken: String! = credentials.token.description

         print("\n\n##### didUpdatePushCredentials: \n\n", voipToken)

        **// update server with device token HERE**

    }


    func pushRegistry(registry: PKPushRegistry!, didReceiveIncomingPushWithPayload payload: PKPushPayload!, forType type: String!) {

        print("\n\n##  DID RECEIVE NOTIFICATION ## \n\n")
        let data = payload.dictionaryPayload
        let aps = data["aps"] as! [String: AnyObject]
        let alert = aps["alert"] as! [String: AnyObject]
        let localNotification = UILocalNotification()

        //setup the notification
        localNotification.alertBody = alert["body"] as? String
        localNotification.alertTitle = alert["title"] as? String
        localNotification.soundName = "Simple_ring_tone_29s.aiff"
        localNotification.alertAction = alert["action-loc-key"] as? String

        UIApplication.sharedApplication().applicationIconBadgeNumber = 1

         //show the notification
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().presentLocalNotificationNow(localNotification)

    }
```

Comment: What is the purpose behind this? if i am not wrong you just want to get push notification while you are in particular view controller.

Comment: Hi, no, I want to register for notifications while in a particular viewcontroller, and for PushKit in Appdelegate to update

Comment: And if you come back from particular viewcontroller then notification should not come, right ? again when you go to particular view controller it will ask you for notification permission.

Comment: No, I always want to receive notifications... I just want to ASK the user in AskForVOIPNotificationsViewController, and I want AppDelegate to register this permission, run didUpdatePushCredentials etc

Comment: add this in brdge #import "PushKit/PKPushRegistry.h"

Comment: Bridge, don´t have a bridge, and why would I add it in a bridge ?

Comment: Ok, if you dont have any other objective c files in projects then no need to add in bridge.

Comment: Is your problem resolved? then close this question.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me, I hope that also work for you.

Still it is not good idea to do, this stuff has to be in appdelegate.

[Please download code.](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7ooURy3zGWKaGxGZVV4X0Y0d3M/view?usp=sharing)

```
//
//  ViewController.swift
//  PushDemo
//
//  Created by Hasya.Panchasra on 01/07/16.
//  Copyright © 2016 bv. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit
import PushKit


class ViewController: UIViewController,PKPushRegistryDelegate {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.PushKitRegistration()
    
}



override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}



//MARK: - PushKitRegistration

func PushKitRegistration()
{
    
    let mainQueue = dispatch_get_main_queue()
    // Create a push registry object
    if #available(iOS 8.0, *) {
        
        let voipRegistry: PKPushRegistry = PKPushRegistry(queue: mainQueue)
        
        // Set the registry's delegate to self
        
        voipRegistry.delegate = self
        
        // Set the push type to VoIP
        
        voipRegistry.desiredPushTypes = [PKPushTypeVoIP]
        
    } else {
        // Fallback on earlier versions
    }
    
    
}


@available(iOS 8.0, *)
func pushRegistry(registry: PKPushRegistry!, didUpdatePushCredentials credentials: PKPushCredentials!, forType type: String!) {
    // Register VoIP push token (a property of PKPushCredentials) with server
    
    let hexString : String = UnsafeBufferPointer<UInt8>(start: UnsafePointer(credentials.token.bytes),
        count: credentials.token.length).map { String(format: "%02x", $0) }.joinWithSeparator("")
    
    print(hexString)
    
    
}


@available(iOS 8.0, *)
func pushRegistry(registry: PKPushRegistry!, didReceiveIncomingPushWithPayload payload: PKPushPayload!, forType type: String!) {
    // Process the received push
    
    
}

}
```

---

```
 func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

           
    let types: UIRemoteNotificationType = [.Alert, .Badge, .Sound]
    application.registerForRemoteNotificationTypes(types)
    
    return true
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

From the code you've posted, it seems the only place you call `registerForVoIPPushes()`, is in `application(_:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:)`

Since `registerForVoIPPushes()` sets the voip registry delegate, you should probably also call it when the user gives permission for notifications.

According to [this tutorial](http://pierremarcairoldi.com/ios-8-voip-notifications/), `registerUserNotificationSettings(userNotificationSettings)` has a delegate callback `application(_:didRegisterWithNotificationSettings:)` you can use for this purpose:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didRegisterUserNotifications notificationSettings: UIUserNotificationSettings)
{
    // Check whether notifications are permitted
    if notificationSettings != .None
    {
        print("Permission for notifications granted.")
        registerForVoIPPushes()
    }
}
```